# Showing unbiased MLE in Normal distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, conditional-expectation, maximum-likelihood

I apologise greatly in advance... I have been asked to show that the MLE for a normal distribution $X_i \sim N(\mu z_i, 1)$ is

$$ \hat{\mu} = \frac{\sum^{n}_{i=1} z_ix_i}{\sum^{n}_{i=1} z_i^2}$$

which is fine. I now want to prove that this estimator is unbiased. So clearly I have;

$$ E\left[ \hat{\mu} \right] = E\left[ \frac{\sum^{n}_{i=1} z_ix_i}{\sum^{n}_{i=1} z_i^2} \right]
$$

And I know I'm looking to get this back to $\mu z_i$ but I'm just lost with this quotient and expectation. I don't see how I can carry the expectation through the quotient. A hint provided is to remember that the $z_i$ are constants. Which I guess is so at some point I will have $E\left[ x_iz_i \right] = z_i E\left[ x_i \right]$ but that's about it.

Again, so sorry that this is such a simple question!

Comment: Hint: Let $$u=\sum\limits^{n}_{i=1} z_i^2$$ then, for every $k$, $$E[ z_kx_ku^{-1}\mid z_1,\ldots,z_n]=z_ku^{-1}E[ x_k\mid z_1,\ldots,z_n]=z_ku^{-1}\cdot\mu z_k
$$ hence $$E[ z_kx_ku^{-1}]=\mu\cdot E[z_k^2u^{-1}]$$ Summing these, one gets $$E\left[u^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^n z_kx_k\right]=\ldots$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Sadly I am still lost. Do I need to show that $E[\hat{\mu}] = \mu z_i$ or that $E[\hat{\mu}] = \mu$? Thanks again!

Comment: "I now want to prove that this estimator is unbiased" An estimator $W$ of a parameter $w$ is unbiased if $E(W)=w$, no? Hence...